# How can we auto-generate a new folder for every new user of our android app on Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

Currently, data of all the users who are using my Android app is going to a single folder on Firebase Storage. But I want to auto-create a new folder for every new device. Means, the data of "harry's device" will be uploaded to "Harry Folder" on storage of Firebase. And the data of "Jane's device" will be auto uploaded to "Jane Folder".

Note: I want the auto-creation of folders on Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use names, use UID of users as it is unique.
Whenever uploading data to firebase use this:

```
private void uploadMethod() {
        progressDialog();
        StorageReference storageReferenceProfilePic = firebaseStorage.getReference();
        StorageReference imageRef = storageReferenceProfilePic.child(firebaseUser.getUid() + "/" + "image" + ".jpg");

        imageRef.putFile(profilePicUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //if the upload is successful
                        //hiding the progress dialog
                        //and displaying a success toast
                        dismissDialog();
                        profilePicUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        //if the upload is not successful
                        //hiding the progress dialog
                        dismissDialog();
                        //and displaying error message
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.getCause().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //calculating progress percentage
//                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
//                        //displaying percentage in progress dialog
//                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                    }
                });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are no auto create of specific firebase cloud storage location when 
a new user registers to your app. but you can achieve this manually by naming your folder base on user id.